# How create a Query to search in Laravel?

Tags: laravel-5, search

I am using laravel 5.2 and I am trying to create search functionality where I am trying to query through multiple columns but I am not getting expected result.

I am using this query:

```
    $wachat = Table::where('key', '=', $d1) 
    ->orWhere('message', 'LIKE', "%{$searchByContact}%")
    ->orWhere('abc', 'LIKE', "%{$searchByContact}%")
    ->orWhere('xyz', 'LIKE', "%{$searchByContact}%")
    ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(20);
```

I am getting results but here I want to filter everything where a key is anything. But with the aboove query, I am getting a result from all key is there anyway I can create a query and then just display result where a key is anything.

Comment: Couldn't you just remove the first `where` method?

Comment: I need to search and give me a result where key is $d1 searching is fine but give me a result where key is matching. In this case I am getting result from all

Comment: Trying just using `::where('key', $d1)`

Comment: ::where('key', $d1) is not filtering

Comment: I'm writing an answer for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are using `->orWhere()` methods, which will cancel out the previous calls search criteria.

You should use a `->where()` closure for the second part of the query:

```
$wachat = Table::where('key', '=', $d1) 
    ->where(function($query) use ($searchByContact) {
        $query->where('message', 'LIKE', "%{$searchByContact}%")
            ->orWhere('abc', 'LIKE', "%{$searchByContact}%")
            ->orWhere('xyz', 'LIKE', "%{$searchByContact}%");
    })
    ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
    ->paginate(20);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer